Hover псевдоэлементов при display: contents
Если навести мышку на ::before или ::after элемента, к которому применён display: contents, то в хроме :hover срабатывает, а в FF и Safari - нет.

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы срабатывал?
А какой браузер прав? Мне кажется, что хром.



section::before, section::after {
  content: "pseudo";
  display: block;
  line-height: 2;
}

section {
  display: contents;
}

section:hover {
  color: red;
}
<section>
  <div>real</div>
</section>




К сожалению, адекватно реализовать это не получиться, по спецификации CSS - псевдоэлементы ::before и ::after не являются реальными элементами в DOM, и поэтому во многих браузерах они не могут быть целевыми для событий. В данном случае скорее не прав хром.

вот в таком варианте, у  меня в обоих браузерах поведение одинаковое

Кто не знает, пример на чистом css. это не LESS, sass и не scss



section {
    display: contents;
    

    &::before,
    &::after {
        content: "pseudo";
        display: block;
        line-height: 4;
    }

    &:hover {
        color: red;
        
    }
}
<section>
  <div>real</div>
</section>



Хотя странно, в документации поддержка полная и поведение должно быть одинаковым.

В FF не работает вообще (115.10.0esr)

@ESkri, автор ответа забыл упомянуть, что данный синтаксис CSS работает по умолчанию с определённых версий браузеров: Chrome и Edge со 120, Сафари с 17.2, FF с 117 и т.д..

Спасибо за пояснение.  А к автору ответа - вопрос "А зачем так сильно бежать впереди паровоза?" )))  Мой FF считает, что он обновлён до самой последней версии.

Ну т. е. ты перенёс псевдоэлементы с section на div, но вместо понятного div::before поставил section ::before (и остальные 2 селектора аналогично). Ну, в некоторых случаях может быть решением...

@Qwertiy, я не переносил ничего.  Эта  запись в моем примере аналогична  section::before, section::after, но почему-то в новом синтаксисе у примера другое поведение

После того, как ты пробелы удалил, работает совершенно одинаково с кодом из вопроса.

@Qwertiy, ты прав. Но как я понял, пробелов быть не должно.  С пробелом бы обращаешься   к элементу дочернему  div{& .s{color:red;}} (div у которого есть дочерний элемент с  класс-ом s ), а без пробела к  самому  div{&.s{color:red;}} (div у которого есть класс s )

@Qwertiy, но вот, что касается псевдо элементов. и так работает и так.  Хотя если логический поразмыслить, ты обращаешься к самому  элементу и в нем создаешь псевдо элемент. Пробела быть не должно.

@Air, перечитай мой первый комментарий. Именно это делает пробел.

элемент к которому применен display: contents с точки зрения иерархии как кукушка "сбагривает" потомков ближайшему предку, а после прикидывается их братом. так что нет, хром скорее не прав чем прав.
учитывая что версии браузеров в вопросе не указаны, возможно у вас устаревший хром. настолько устаревший, что попросту не поддерживает display: contents(иль поддерживает, но с ошибками)

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы срабатывал?

раз уж псевды в таком случае не дети секции а братья(находятся рядом с ним а не в нём), надо смотреть на братскую селекцию. а это очень веселая штука:


#x > *{border: 1px solid red}
#x>*:hover ~ *{background: red;} /* кто выше триггера тот и игнорит селектор */
<div id='x'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>



и да, как подметили выше - это ПСЕВДОэлементы, а не полноценные элементы, потому и результат печальный, увы...


#y{display: contents}
#y:after, #y:before{content: 'abc'; display: block;}
#x *:hover {color: red}
<div id='x'>
  <div id='y'>
  a
  </div>
</div>



самое вменяемое решение - отказ от display: contents в пользу обычного врапера.
по крайней мере мне, найти приличный способ использования contents, пока не удалось...
UPD

В какой ситуации его можно рассматривать как их брата?

вот вам GRID, развлекайтесь.


.x{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr, 5);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1fr, 5);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  background: pink;
  }
.y{ /*!!!!!!!*/
  grid-column: 1;
  background: red;
  display: contents;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.z{display: list-item}
.z:nth-child(1){
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  background: gold;
}
.z:nth-child(4){
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  background: gold;
}
.z:nth-child(2){
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2 / span 4;
  background: green;
}
.x:hover .z:nth-child(2){display: none} /*!!!!!*/
.z:nth-child(3){
  grid-row: 2 / span 4;
  grid-column: 4;
  background: brown;
}

.y:after, .y:before, .z:after{
  content: attr(class) ' ' counter(list-item);
  background: silver;
}
.y:after{grid-column: 5; grid-row: span 3}
<div class='x'>
  <div class='y'>
    <div class='z'></div>
    <div class='z'></div>
    <div class='z'></div>
    <div class='z'></div>
    йа есть content`s
  </div>
</div>




"а после прикидывается их братом" - что? Правильнее было бы сказать, что он как бы исчезает. В какой ситуации его можно рассматривать как их брата? Не могу придумать никакой подобной ситуации. "отказ от display: contents в пользу обычного врапера" - вообще не решение) "найти приличный способ использования contents, пока не удалось" - а вот этого - огромное количество вариантов.

@Qwertiy, докинул в ответ сниппет с примером. пусть и частичным. огромное кол-во ну... сомнительных кмк...
